# Why does my naive Bayes classifier only give me probabilities near 0?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

I'm building a text classifier using the naive Bayes formula. I'm still early in the development, but I already see a problem with my technique and I was wondering if you guys would have idea that would help me solve this problem.

What I want to do is score texts to order them from the more likely to be in class A to the less likely to be. I only have one class and I want to find the likelyhood that a text is in it.

The problem is I only get prediction really near zero (1,068E-12 for exemple). the reason is most words have a probability of being in class A inferior to 0.5. Even if I have words with probabilities > 0.5, theses probabilities are farther from 1 then the probabilities <0.5 are farther from 0.

So when I choose the N words with the probabilities the farthest from .05 I usually get only (or at least more) probabilities <0.5. And so the more words I use (N) the more the probability is near 0.

Is there some optimization I could implement that would help with this problem (For now I don't even remove stop words, but I plan to)?

Or is a Bayes classifier a bad choice for my problem?

Answer (score 9):

Naive Bayes generally uses a decision rule like
$$
\text{argmax}_{C_i} P(C_i)P(D|C_i), 
$$
which comes from the fact we can write
$$
P(C_i|D) = \frac{P(C_i)P(D|C_i)}{P(D)}.
$$
and drop the denominator $P(D)$ since it does not depend on the class. However, since $P(D) << 1$ (i.e. there are many possible documents), neglecting it will cause the output of your algorithm to be quite small, so this isn't necessarily indication your implementation is incorrect.

A practical tip: One thing you can and should do is work with sums of log probabilities rather than products of probabilities to avoid underflow errors. Rather than doing
$$
P(D|C_i) = \prod_{w_j \in D} P(w_j|C_i),
$$
do
$$
\log P(D|C_i) = \sum_{w_j \in D} \log P(w_j|C_i).
$$
You'll also need to deal with unseen words as well since zero probabilities will give you problems.

Comment: Hi alto. Thanks for answering. I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, so tell me if I understand your last equation correctly. The probability of document D being of class Ci is the sum of the logarithms of the probabilities of a document containing the word wj being of class Ci. Is that right?

Comment: Also, does this give me probabilities or just relatives scores?

Comment: Not that I currently used the formula presented here : http://www.paulgraham.com/naivebayes.html which I'm not sure is equivalent to your first equation. Maybe I started with the wrong algorithm. I'll go read more on naive Bayes.

Comment: I think you are reading the conditional backwards. $P(D|C)$ should be read the probability of a document given the class, not the other way around. The wiki page has a good example in the context of document classification [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Document_Classification). It might be easier to read through this and then allow us to clear anything up which might be giving you problems afterward.